# How to verify if localization is working correctly in Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I have used RView and MAT tools to create resource files for french language as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize to localize the form flow. How can I verify if the localization is working correctly. Basically I need a way to test the form flow in my emulator in French language. 
What's the best/right way to set the **CurrentUICulture** or to test this out?

Comment: Are you asking how to simulate french culture in emulator? If so, you can just click the entry for url and use `fr` for `Locale` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9ByC.png).

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thanks! That's what I wanted. Just one more question, how does the culture get set for a real user in ms teams channel.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, usually we determine the locale by prompting the user, let user choose a preferred language, do you want to make your bot automatically change the language according to user's client channel?

Comment: Or do you want to determine the locale by user inputs?

Comment: I was considering options @GraceFeng-MSFT. Like you mentioned - Prompting user as well as automatic detection. But I guess I will go with the prompting user method. Are there any samples available for that, like where to store the selected language - should it be in state or somewhere else, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set locale in bot emulator like this:

[image]

Then the point problem is that whether Bot SDK can get locale info from client channels  and automatically set culture info based on that. I couldn't find any official documents that can point out this problem, we can only run test on that.

If the bot can't get locale from client side, there're two workarounds to solve this issue.

1. To prompt user, show dialog to let user choose preferred language, and then we can save user's choice for example in a table of azure storage.
2. Use [Text Analytics API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/) to automatically detect the user's language based upon user's input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your locale set to e.g. French all the time (i.e. for the entire conversation), you can set the locale in the activity in MessagesController.cs before calling the dialog, like so:

```
activity.Locale ="fr";
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
```

It is mentioned in the documentation that activity.Locale overrides the culture of the thread in which the dialogs are used. Because of this, you would have a hard time setting the culture yourself manually in the dialogs.