# Localization in bot framework .Net

Tags: c#, localization, botframework

I am trying to achieve localization in bot framework (C#) and have found some resources for it too.

For form flow -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize

For prompt dialogs and normal messages -> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers#localization

But the main problem here is that, both these depend on the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` value. Testing it out in emulator was easy by setting the locale ( [How to verify if localization is working correctly in Bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959242/how-to-verify-if-localization-is-working-correctly-in-bot-framework) ), but how will it be set in case of a real user accessing it through a channel.

In case `CurrentUICulture` is not the right way, how can we achieve localization? Is setting it in state another viable option?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization provides localization documentation for **nodejs**, is there any similar approach to determine the locale by prompting the user in ***Bot framework C# SDK***

Any code samples would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to prompt the user using the dotnet SDK, it should automatically set the current culture to that of the incoming message.

You can see this working here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=localizedscope&type=

If you want to ignore the user locale, and instead prompt the user to pick a language, you can see a sample of this in action here: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ChooseLanguageBot

The jist of building a language picker is that you need to create a dialog inheriting from `IDialog<object>` which sends a `PromptDialog` with valid language options if a language hasn't been chosen already. once the user picks a language then save the locale chosen locale. You can use the context to store it: `context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue("SOME_KEY", optionSelected.Locale);`

Comment: Will the current culture be set automatically for all the channels like msteams, webchat, etc.

Comment: The culture gets set automatically from `IMessageActivity.Locale` which comes from the request. This should be populated automatically by clients, but I've not tested myself. Feel free to trust that MS has taken care of this already, do your own testing, or ignore the work they've done and implement it yourself with a language picker - it's up to you.

Comment: Here's the answer on the issue of automatically detecting locale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959242/how-to-verify-if-localization-is-working-correctly-in-bot-framework?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks @caesay for explaining in detail as well as providing alternatives :).